# Intellisense quick fix

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

I'm using a machine with installed Arch Linux and Windows 10. Both of them have Visual Studio Code installed. But, on Arch Linux every unknown definitions can be easily picked up trhough `CTRL+.`. On Windows I haven't this option. How can I enable this feature on Windows?[image: Arch][image: Windows 10].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code Intellisense not working for Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235242/visual-studio-code-intellisense-not-working-for-javascript)

Comment: Man, checked that article already. I'm not trying to download that manually. I want to have that .d.ts files automatically downloaded by VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Updates) in "No longer supported" it says, that this feature is now disabled. So, I looked at the version in Arch, it was 0.10.6 and downloaded  the same release on Windows. Works like a charm. I hope, that this feature will be returned after some time. But for now the solution is to downgrade VS Code

Comment: There will be a typings Extension for vscode in the future https://github.com/typings/vscode. This extension will have the feature "Automatically detect and install typings". In the meantime you can use https://github.com/typings/typings command line tool to manually install type definitions.

Comment: You mean, that soon there will be no need to `CTRL+.` to pick up a definitions, they will be loaded automatically? Hooray! Give this gentleman a beer :)

Comment: This new extension might be interesting for you: https://github.com/jvitor83/typings-autoinstaller

Comment: @Steffen , could you please provide some aditional information about this? Becuase I cannot figure out, how to use it. I've installed package, but something is wrong. I can' t download typings when savings package.json

Comment: This could be the same issue I had when I first installed this extension. I had to restart vscode before it worked. If it is working you should see logging information in the output window. In the upper right of the output window you have to switch to the logging context of the extension.

Comment: @Steffen, I think, it is just not my day :) Look, here's the [output](http://tinypic.com/r/nybtr9/9)

Comment: I have checked the code of the extension at 99:30 where the error occurs. It is a JSON.parse call and it is parsing your bower.json. The error message "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" indicates that there is a syntax error in the file. You could try to [validate](http://jsonlint.com/) the json of the file. Hope this helps.

Comment: [This](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ax1ef7&s=9) is the expected behavior after `npm install jquery --save`

Comment: @Steffen, yep, just figured, that it won't work, if I will not create bower.json. But I'm not using it. It says, that it will grab files for package.json, maybe that feature is only for specific OS?

Comment: @Steffen, oh, I got it, only bower can work with front end. But either way, after saving, plugin not downloading all that stuff automatically. The console errors log is empty

Comment: Does it work if you run `Typings: Install definitions for all dependencies` from command palette (<kbd>F1</kbd>)? Can you see any logging in Output panel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)?

Comment: @Steffen, No, the [output](http://tinypic.com/r/mlurm/9) is clear. The auto-downloading not working, alas

Answer (score -1):

it is called 'Quick Fix',[keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)
and in official [cheatsheet](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)，this option is reachable，you may check your extensions

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead