# Visual studio code IntelliSense not working with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code, config

I had been working with vs code for a while to develop NodeJS projects however IntelliSense not working for the classes and files I am writing, I had tried the solution inside [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235242/visual-studio-code-intellisense-not-working-for-javascript)  but it did not work for me, so anyone can help me to fix this problem.

VS code version:1.25.0

NodeJS version:8.9.4

An example about IntelliSense problem:

[image: This is a simple class]
This is a simple class

[image: As you can see when I am importing it from another file no IntelliSense is working]
As you can see when I am importing it from another file no IntelliSense is working
[image: But the node_module files IntelliSense is working]
But the node_module files IntelliSense is working!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve it with a different syntax to export the class:

```js
class Util {
    constructor() { }

    getNumber(x, y) {
        return x * y;
    }
}

exports.default = Util;
```

Then, I could import the class like this

```js
const util = require('./../util/util').default;
```

And the autocompletion works:

[image]