# Visual Studio Code IntelliSense not working for Node.js

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have gone through the following threads before posting this question.

[Visual Studio Code: Intellisense not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389852/visual-studio-code-intellisense-not-working)

[Visual Studio Code Intellisense not working for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235242/visual-studio-code-intellisense-not-working-for-javascript)

I have Visual Studio version 1.26.1 on my Windows 10 laptop.

I am learning Node.Js, so I wanted to learn various functionalities in 'FS' module. I created a new file called 'app1.js' in Visual Studio Code, and wrote the following line of code.

fsObj = require('fs');

After this when I typed **fsObj.** to see what functions/properties are available under the fs object, I get a list with only two objects, which are not elements of the 'fs' module. I do not understand why IntelliSense is not showing the elemetns of 'fs' module.  I am pasting a screen shot of the VS Code screen.

[image]

Comment: Those typings should be automatically downloaded, assuming you have node  installed.  You have   "typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition": false, unchanged in your settings?  And   "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": true, ?  Those are the defaults which you don't want to change.

Comment: where are these settings? if these settings are in VS Code, how do I access it?

Comment: The gear icon in the lower left - then 'Settings'.  Then you can 'Search Settings': you should find those two settings in the left panel (which is readonly) and not in the right panel at all if they haven't been changed.  I also assume you have internet access so that vscode can download the files necessary for the intellisense.  And you installed node?  Sorry, basic questions just in case.

Comment: I have checked these settings and they are unchanged. The strange thing is that if I create a new folder and open that new folder in a new window of VS Code, then I am not facing this issue.  But if I open the same folder (in which i see this issue) in a new VS code instance, then I still see this issue. Could this be related to something inside the folder?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, does putting const in front of the variable make any difference?  It looks like it does for me.  So:  const fsObj = …. or let or var.

Comment: Just another of the problems with creating a global variable it appears.

Comment: adding const in front of the variable worked!. But I would like to understand why it works like this. You can add your comment as answer and I will accept it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KurioZ7 - for me (in Jul 2019) once I had the settings right and a` jsconfig.json` file, again the intellisense did not immediately work in an existing project. But just creating a new `.js` file in that folder *did* kick intellisense into action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `const`, `let` or `var` before your variable `fsObj`, that variable has a 'global' scope.  Something about that seems to prevent vscode from being able to assign the proper intellisense parameters to that variable.  Adding one of those, like `const`, provides a different scope where the intellisense works.  I cannot explain exactly what is preventing intellisense, perhaps the variable is bound to something higher in the scope chain that prevents it working.

In any case, failing to include `const/let/var` would result in an error if strict mode was used.