# javascript Intellisense works on <script> of html but not in .js file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Using Visual Studio Code, intellisense is not working correctly in a `.js` file. VSCODE version 1.56.2 (user setup)

[image: No intellisense in .js file]

The intellisense does work correctly in a `<script>` tag within a `.html` file.

[image: Intellisense is working in script tag of html]

I tried the steps in [Visual Studio Code Intellisense not working for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235242/visual-studio-code-intellisense-not-working-for-javascript) but it's not working either.

Comment: provide VScode version

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit VScode 1.56.2 Also added in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help but I figured it out.
It was an in-built pre-disabled extension for JavaScript and typescript

[image: Extension]

Answer (score 0):

try the following extension
[Visual Studio IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode)

and restart your VSCode and System

Answer (score -1):

try to install this extension in your VS Code :

[image]

Comment: I had that installed already when I was facing the issue, uninstalling or reinstalling this extension made no changes.