# Intellisense is not working in Node.js module in WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

Just had Node.js installed in my WSL2 according to the instruction here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl

However, I noticed that IntelliSense is not working for Node.js  and I am not able to see the declarations file by hovering and clicking on the fs variable.

Have gone through some other threads but still can't find any solutions to it.

Update: Only Nodejs modules are not having autocompletion
[Visual Studio Code Intellisense not working for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235242/visual-studio-code-intellisense-not-working-for-javascript)

[Visual Studio Code: Intellisense not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389852/visual-studio-code-intellisense-not-working)

[image: VS code screenshot]

Comment: ... did you install `@types/node@<major version number of your node installation>` for this workspace yet?

Comment: i don't think we need to explicitly install right if i am working with a single js file as the editor usually have built-in support for IntelliSense which can provide auto completion

Comment: please try it. I think you do. TypeScript does not bundle types for NodeJS. AFAIK, you need to install them manually.